# An alternative to 1=2 in sql

Tags: sql, t-sql

Is there any alternative, more elegant, expression to 1=2 that can be used in where clauses in sql?

Something resembling `WHERE false`

Couldn't find an answer to this in google.

**EDIT:**

In languages such as C++ the expressions (1==2) and 0 are equivalent, why doesn't TSQL accept `false` or `true` as a condition?

Comment: Where do you need that?

Comment: Your question is very much unclear. Please add more inputs.

Comment: This is likely in reference to some sort of dynamically generated sql statement in which you're adding a lot of where clause items among unions - for parts of the query that due to parameters input, require no results to be returned 1=2 could be used.  I'm only guessing this because I had to deal with a few horrendous queries doing the same thing :)

Comment: If this is a dynamically generated `where` clause with `or` connectors, just put them together as `or <clause>` and then remove the first `or ` when you put the query together.

Comment: I asked this out of general interest - so is this in principle considered a bad practice?

Comment: I wonder if you could use `1=0.9999999999...`

Comment: I go with `where 0 = 1`, it feels more computerey...

Comment: What about `NOT 1=1`?

Comment: @Dan 1=0.999999999... sounds like Russian roulette

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, TSQL defines `WHERE` clause as `WHERE <search_condition>`  with a variety of "complex?" syntax that excludes an "expression result". Here is the reference for ["search_condition"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173545.aspx).

`False`, `4` are expressions results.

What you expect is perhaps more logical, as `WHERE` acts as a in/out gate, and of course any of the "search_condition" evaluated, represents a boolean. But for TSQL it must be a "search_condition" and not a boolean evaluable expression.

Ms-Access works in the way you mention, where the `WHERE` clause acts ONLY, yes, only on the evaluation of the expression.

This are valid in Ms-Access

```
where false                --  excludes all
where 4                    --  includes all, as casts to true
where mycolumn = 'aa'      --  depends on mycolumn content
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly I think `1=2` is itself elegant. So you need to specify exactly in which situation or how you are using it. Next `1=2` specify a false condition(*which you are already aware of*). This is used mostly when you want to check for a false condition something like when you want to create the schema of the table without copying the data. A similar thing is `1=1` which is used for true condition.

Also as far as performance is concerned I think `1=2` will be a better option(*but I am not 100% sure about that*)

Answer (score 1):

you can also use **false** key word in the where clause as well.

Comment: why aren't (false) and (1=2) equivalent? both are fallacies

Comment: `WHERE` requires a `search_condition`, and cannot use an expression result. That's just how it's defined. Argue with Microsoft if you believe it to be illogical, but you must obey the rules.